# How to control listen action in watson unity sdk?

Tags: unity-game-engine, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

I am working on speech-to-text project in Unity3D . And I'm very new on this topic, so trying to modify Watson Unity SDK's demo to understand how it works. I am trying to stop and start the listening action of Speech-toText function, but it listens and converts to text non-stop. Is there anyone can direct me to the area I should look?

I am using Unity 5.3.4p4. and I have downloaded the SDK from here - https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/unity-sdk

thanks

Answer (score 6):

The microphone widget is the component that is actually getting audio from the device. In the example you should be able to call `OnToggleActive()` on the microphone widget to stop sending data to SpeechToText.

The SpeechToText abstraction also has a method to `StartListening()` and `StopListening()`.

Comment: I solved that disabling the microphone using the public methods ActivateMicrophone and DeactivateMicrophone on MicrophoneWidget.